# How to format LocalDate to string?

Tags: java, jsr310

I have a `LocalDate` variable called `date`, when I print it displays 1988-05-05 I need to convert this to be printed as 05.May 1988. How to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the [DateTimeFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.  It even has examples of how to convert to and from `String`s.

Comment: You should show some code, what you have tried so far and what's not working so people can help you.

Comment: I tried to do that but because of this annoying "it does not meet our quality standards" thing  I  finally gave up,it took me 15 minutes just to post this because i had to correct "i" with "I".

Answer (score 469, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat will not work if he is starting with LocalDate which is new in Java 8.  From what I can see, you will have to use DateTimeFormatter, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();//For reference
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd LLLL yyyy");
String formattedString = localDate.format(formatter);
```

That should print 05 May 1988.  To get the period after the day and before the month, you might have to use "dd'.LLLL yyyy"

Comment: Thank you very much,this helps,but it didn't work with 'LLLL' to show name of the month but with 'MMMM' i found this strange since even in the documentation it says otherwise.But once again thank you for helping me.

Comment: Now localDate.format(formatter); doesn't work at all

Comment: which version JDK your Using @ProgrammersBlock

Answer (score 106):

Could be short as:

```
LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 15):

## *java.time*

***Unfortunately, all existing answers have missed a crucial thing, `Locale`.***

A date-time parsing/formatting type (e.g. `DateTimeFormatter` of the modern API or `SimpleDateFormat` of the legacy API) is `Locale`-sensitive. The symbols used in its pattern print the text based on the `Locale` used with them. In absence of a `Locale`, it uses the default `Locale` of the JVM. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) to learn more about it.

The text in the expected output, `05.May 1988` is in English and thus, the existing solutions will produce the expected result only as a result of mere coincidence (when the default `Locale` of the JVM an English `Locale`).

**Solution using `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(1988, 5, 5);
        final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MMMM uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String output = dtf.format(date);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
05.May 1988
```

Here, you can use `yyyy` instead of `uuuu` but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 8):

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MMMM yyyy")));
```

*The above answer shows it for today*

Comment: ofPatterns needs android O

Answer (score 0):

With the help of ProgrammersBlock posts I came up with this.  My needs were slightly different.  I needed to take a string and return it as a LocalDate object.  I was handed code that was using the older Calendar and SimpleDateFormat.  I wanted to make it a little more current.  This is what I came up with.

```
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;


    void ExampleFormatDate() {

    LocalDate formattedDate = null;  //Declare LocalDate variable to receive the formatted date.
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter;  //Declare date formatter
    String rawDate = "2000-01-01";  //Test string that holds a date to format and parse.

    dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;

    //formattedDate.parse(String string) wraps the String.format(String string, DateTimeFormatter format) method.
    //First, the rawDate string is formatted according to DateTimeFormatter.  Second, that formatted string is parsed into
    //the LocalDate formattedDate object.
    formattedDate = formattedDate.parse(String.format(rawDate, dateTimeFormatter));

}
```

Hopefully this will help someone, if anyone sees a better way of doing this task please add your input.

Comment: I see a better way: just `LocalDate.parse(rawDate)` ! `String.format` is being used in a total wrong form here, actually just returning the first string; the `DateTimeFormatter` is not being used at all; `parse` is a `static` method of `LocalDate`;  `formattedDate` is **not** a formatted date, not even a `String` (as requested in question)

Answer (score -5):

**There is a built-in way to format LocalDate** in **Joda library**

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
String dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
localDate.toString(dateFormat);
```

In case you don't have it already - add this to the build.gradle:

```
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.5'
```

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Not according to the javadoc.

Comment: @Edward, if it's not, please prove it and provide a solution you think is better.

Comment: you want me to prove that LocalDate.toString(String pattern) does NOT exist? Please provide a reference to that method if it does exist - I haven't been able to find it in any javadocs. As for a solution, this question already has that.

Comment: @Edward, Looks like you are having a hard time finding it. Updated my answer.

Comment: Joda Time is not "built-in". OP seems to be using java.time.LocalDate, not joda.time

Comment: We are using `org.joda.time.LocalDate` for ages, OP may be using it as well.

Comment: Yes, this is the way for joda time. Thank you @Inoy

Answer (score -18):

A pretty nice way to do this is to use `SimpleDateFormat` I'll show you how:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM YYYY");
Date d = new Date();
sdf.format(d);
```

I see that you have the date in a variable:

```
sdf.format(variable_name);
```

Cheers.

Comment: OP wants to print the content of a `LocalDate` instance in a specific format. How could `SimpleDateFormat` help him here?