# Java LocalDate Formatting

Tags: java, date, localdate

Looking for some help with LocalDate, I have so far come up with this:

```
public static String getDate(int days) {    
  LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2017, 03, 04).plusDays(days);    
  return localDate.toString():
}
```

I need to return it as a string, but in this format: dd/mm/yyyy = 29/04/1991.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format your date as a string

Comment: What did your research turn up? In what way was it insufficient? Tip: You may sometimes get faster answers from your search engine than from waiting for someone to type an answer here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tom, it’s not an exact duplicate, but there’s certainly a wealth of good inspiration to be found in the question you are linking to.

Comment: @OleV.V. You may should re-read what "duplicate" means :).

Comment: Could be, @Tom. Where do you suggest I start reading? Asking after having done a superficial search myself and not finding much interesting. Mostly [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: Also a dup of [How to format LocalDate to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28177370/642706)

Answer (score 2):

use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
                  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy" );
return LocalDate.of(2017, 03, 04).plusDays(days).format(formatter);
```

Comment: or return LocalDate.of(2017, 03, 04).plusDays(days).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));