# Create a list of String elements entitles according to dates

Tags: scala

I want to create a list of String elements, each one having a date in its title:

```
data_2017_May_4
data_2017_May_3
data_2017_May_2
```

The important thing is how these dates are created. They should be created starting from current date till minus 2 days. If the current date is May 1 2017, then the result would be:

```
data_2017_May_1
data_2017_April_30
data_2017_April_29
```

The same logic is applied to the switch between years (December/January).

This is my code, but it does not consider the changes of months and years. Also it jumps in dates:

```
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd")
val currDay = Calendar.getInstance

var list: List[String] = Nil
var day = null
var date: String = ""
for (i <- 0 to 2) {
  currDay.add(Calendar.DATE, -i)
  date = "data_"+formatter.format(currDay.getTime)
  list ::= date
}
println(list.mkString(","))
```

How to reach the objective?

Comment: `if (/* day */ <= 2) { //decrement month` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use java.time.LocalDate? If so you can easily accomplish this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val desiredFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd")

val now = LocalDate.now()
val dates = Set(now, now.minusDays(1), now.minusDays(2))

dates.map(_.format(desiredFormat))
  .foreach(date => println(s"data_$date"))
```

Comment: Beautiful! In which cases it is not recommendable to use `LocalDate`?

Comment: When you need access to the timestamp, as a LocalDate does not contain that information. One can look into LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime, or even Instant which are available in the java.time library.

Comment: There is one pending issue in this solution. How to use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd")` with `LocalDate`?

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177370/how-to-format-localdate-to-string

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is that I get error message `Cannot resolve symbol ofPattern`.

Comment: see updated answer - I was able to compile and get the dates printed successfully with that in the REPL

Comment: Now it's ideal.Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it will be interesting for you to answer this relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924922/how-to-automate-the-creation-of-string-elements-with-datetime