# How to automate the creation of String elements with datetime

Tags: scala

This thread arises from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921229/create-a-list-of-string-elements-entitles-according-to-dates). I need to create `Seq[String]` that contains paths as String elements, however now I also need to add numbers `7`,`8`,...-`22` after a date. Also I cannot use `LocalDate` as it was suggested in the answer to the above-cited question:

```
path/file_2017-May-1-7
path/file_2017-May-1-8
...
path/file_2017-May-1-22
path/file_2017-April-30-7
path/file_2017-April-30-8
...
path/file_2017-April-30-22
..
```

I am searching for a flexible solution. My current solution implies the manual definition of dates `yyyy-MMM-dd`. However it is not efficient if I need to include more than 2 dates, e.g. 10 or 100. Moreover `filePathsList` is currently `Set[Seq[String]]` and I don't know how to convert it into `Seq[String]`.

```
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd")
val currDay = Calendar.getInstance
currDay.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
val day_1_ago = currDay.getTime
currDay.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
val day_2_ago = currDay.getTime
val dates = Set(formatter.format(day_1_ago),formatter.format(day_2_ago))

val filePathsList = dates.map(date => {
  val list: Seq.empty[String]
  for (num <- 7 to 22) {
    list :+ s"path/file_$date-$num" + "
  }
  list
})
```

Comment: Set[Seq[String]] can easily be converted to Seq[String] via flatMap

Comment: @Tanjin: I finally did it using `.toSeq.flatten`, however the key question still remains - how to flexibly create such String elements for N dates. not just 2 as it shown in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I was able to achieve what you outlined, adjust the `days` val to configure the amount of days you care about:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar

val currDay = Calendar.getInstance
val days = 5

val dates = currDay.getTime +: List.fill(days){
  currDay.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
  currDay.getTime
}
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd")
val filePathsList = for {
  date <- dates
  num <- 7 to 22
} yield s"path/file_${formatter.format(date)}-$num"
```

Comment: Great! It probably should be `val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd")
    val dates = currDay.getTime +: List.fill(days){
      currDay.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
      formatter.format(currDay.getTime)
    }`

Comment: Could you please explain what `yield` is doing?

Comment: I apologize for not using the formatter - I've updated the answer to reflect it's usage. This explains yield far better than I could: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html